# Transfer data between server and client using XMLHttpRequest object, handle JSON - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json, server, xmlhttprequest

**Transfer data between server and client using XMLHttpRequest object, handle JSON files and work with objects in JavaScript**

**question 1 :**
Write a java-script program (in a file named Targil1Q1.html), which requests a GET request
Using the XMLHttpRequest object from the PHP program (Targil1Q1.php (, send to it) next to
The client (the data file attached to the job named mock_data.json whose top looks like this:

```
 [
 {
 "id":1,
 "first_name":"Florina",
 "last_name":"Head",
 "email":"fhead0@forbes.com",
 "gender":"Female",
 "ip_address":"193.117.115.240"
 },
 {
 "id":2,
 "first_name":"Lusa",
 "last_name":"Ayling",
 "email":"layling1@macromedia.com",
 "gender":"Female",
 "ip_address":"247.233.187.26"
 },
 …
 ]
```

The HTML program will ask the user using a simple person ID number form. also,
The JavaScript program will convert the JSON it received to a JS object and print it in the center
The document as a table containing headings and the details of the person the user entered the identification number
His. The table should show according to the following example that shows the column headings and the row
In which the details of the person with - 1
[**Image table**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqlvQ.png)

**Question 2:**

Write the HTML program in a file named Targil1Q2.html (which you will ask the user to use
A simple form for a person's identification number. Write java-script code) inside Targil1Q2.html (which requests
Request a POST with parameters using the XMLHttpRequest object from the PHP program
(Targil1Q2.php (Read the data file mock_data.json. In the program request parameter
Send the person's ID.
The PHP program will read the mock_data.json file and generate the HTML code of a table that contains it
Titles and the details of the person the user entered his ID number, and will send the table
Next to the client, where the table will be printed according to the following example that shows the column headings and
The line in which the person's details with -1
[**Image table**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqlvQ.png)

**Question 3:**

Write a JavaScript program (in a file named Targil3Q1.html), which requests a POST request
Using the XMLHttpRequest object from the PHP program (Targil3Q1.php (, send to it) next to
The client (the data file attached to the job named quiz.json) image of him on the next page (.
The HTML program will calculate using the JavaScript program will convert the JSON it received
To the JS object.
The program through input that describes the topics of the question areas (sport, maths) will allow
The user has to choose the type of question the user will answer (math or sports).
Note that the question areas need to be taken from the object) in the present file these are the keys
"sport", "maths" (- you need to take into account that the file can contain many more domains
From those in the current file, that is, you do not know in advance what the topics are and how many there are - you
This information is extracted from the object.
The HTML program will be calculated using the JavaScript program and will generate a random number by number
The questions in the selected field to be extracted from the object. For example in math there are 2 questions.
And the program knows this from the object using the array size of the options key. how
Random book computers read on the web (really not complicated - Google search)
The question selected for the user correctly when the options of the answers will be input of
Radio buttons that allow only one correct answer. Note the key language of the question is visible
Like for example q2, which means you will have to connect the number of the question drawn with the string "q", in a jug
Obtain the appropriate key for the question in the object.
The user will select the correct answer and the program will tell him whether the answer is correct or not)
Know it from the object (answer key)

**Bonus question:**
Allow the user to answer another question after answering a question
) That will be displayed instead of the previous question (and answer it. The program will keep some successful questions)
The user answers and informs her at the end of the game (let's say after 4 questions (about some of which she answered)
Right.
[**Code Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivG6y.jpg)

**Two code files needed**

**mock_data.json**

```
[
   {
"id":1,
"first_name":"Florina",
"last_name":"Head",
"email":"fhead0@forbes.com",
"gender":"Female",
"ip_address":"193.117.115.240"
   },
   {"id":2,"first_name":"Lusa","last_name":"Ayling","email":"layling1@macromedia.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"247.233.187.26"},
   {"id":3,"first_name":"Marguerite","last_name":"Peirson","email":"mpeirson2@unc.edu","gender":"Female","ip_address":"241.171.45.22"},
   {"id":4,"first_name":"Rebeka","last_name":"Brabbs","email":"rbrabbs3@usda.gov","gender":"Female","ip_address":"44.228.21.181"},
   {"id":5,"first_name":"Ode","last_name":"Leeder","email":"oleeder4@army.mil","gender":"Male","ip_address":"203.181.82.15"},
   {"id":6,"first_name":"Sly","last_name":"Breeder","email":"sbreeder5@topsy.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"26.91.12.31"},
   {"id":7,"first_name":"Thorvald","last_name":"Bridges","email":"tbridges6@blog.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"145.127.204.252"},
   {"id":8,"first_name":"Alonso","last_name":"Pitsall","email":"apitsall7@hatena.ne.jp","gender":"Male","ip_address":"41.27.229.172"},
   {"id":9,"first_name":"Thor","last_name":"Lynde","email":"tlynde8@foxnews.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"130.116.61.0"},
   {"id":10,"first_name":"Parrnell","last_name":"Haysman","email":"phaysman9@jalbum.net","gender":"Male","ip_address":"214.121.248.210"},
   {"id":11,"first_name":"Rainer","last_name":"Walcot","email":"rwalcota@mapquest.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"40.153.144.192"},
   {"id":12,"first_name":"Nickola","last_name":"Staples","email":"nstaplesb@icq.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"205.176.9.60"},
   {"id":13,"first_name":"Langston","last_name":"Penfold","email":"lpenfoldc@globo.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"171.115.137.183"},
   {"id":14,"first_name":"Mirella","last_name":"Bodill","email":"mbodilld@umich.edu","gender":"Bigender","ip_address":"79.48.191.67"},
   {"id":15,"first_name":"Dunstan","last_name":"Strapp","email":"dstrappe@marriott.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"232.175.141.13"},
   {"id":16,"first_name":"Talbot","last_name":"Pactat","email":"tpactatf@seattletimes.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"99.94.6.23"},
   {"id":17,"first_name":"Beverly","last_name":"Howick","email":"bhowickg@cam.ac.uk","gender":"Female","ip_address":"144.79.46.36"},
   {"id":18,"first_name":"Aubrette","last_name":"Ansteys","email":"aansteysh@webs.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"132.195.181.226"},
   {"id":19,"first_name":"Chaddie","last_name":"Kunkler","email":"ckunkleri@shop-pro.jp","gender":"Genderqueer","ip_address":"238.32.127.190"},
   {"id":20,"first_name":"Rodrigo","last_name":"Lillie","email":"rlilliej@mapquest.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"21.73.42.39"}
]
```

**Quiz.jon**

```
{
"quiz": {
"sport": {
"q1": {
"question":"Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
"options": [
"New York Bulls",
"Los Angeles Kings",
"Golden State Warriros",
"Huston Rocket"
               ],
"answer":"Huston Rocket"
           }
       },
"maths": {
"q1": {
"question":"5 + 7 = ?",
"options": [
"10",
"11",
"12",
"13"
               ],
"answer":"12"
           },
"q2": {
"question":"12 - 8 = ?",
"options": [
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4"
               ],
"answer":"4"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**Thank you very much for the help really thank you to whoever will help**

Comment: Please only post _one_ question per post. Also make sure you post a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (with focus on "minimal".) While you're at it, also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered (which I can see you still haven't taken) to learn how to ask a good, on-point and on-topic question.

Comment: Btw, none of your "questions" are actually questions, they are requirement specifications. There's not a single question in the whole post. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues you might run into while writing, but this is **not**  a free coding service. You need to write your own code (or hire a developer).

Comment: u want i edit to one question ?

Comment: Please read my comments again _including_ all the links I posted (they are to the guidelines on how to use StackOverflow). There are a lot more you need to fix in your post than just the amount of "questions".